# crear varios archivos con diferentes nombres en python

Tags: python

Tengo que crear varios archivos indefinidos cuando el Internet esta desconectado y aguardar un json adentro de cada uno de esos archivos, pero no me sale el crear varios archivos no se como hacer que cree archivo_1, después archivo_2, así consecutivamente ya que no se cuantos archivos se estarán creando,  este es mi código:

```
import subprocess, time
import os
import errno
import json
import urllib2
import socket
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from os import listdir

hostname = "www.google.com"
rootDir = './Json'
nombre = datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H_%M_%S.%f')[:-3]
filename = "Json/%s.json"% nombre


#"Json/%s.json"% time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def net_is_up():
    while(1):
        response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
        if response == 0:
            print "[%s] Network is up!" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            #read_json()
            get_json()

        else: 
            print "[%s] Network is down :(" % time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        time.sleep(.300)

def get_json():
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filename)):
                try:
                    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
                except OSError as exc: # Guard against race condition
                    if exc.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                        raise 
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
                f.write("Da ighual")
```

Comment: Es un poco confusa la pregunta. ¿Cuándo  debes crear un nuevo archivo exactamente?, ¿De qué tipo?, ¿Qué debes guardar en cada uno?, ¿Cómo quieres nombrarlos? Intenta explicar un poco mejor la lógica del programa a ver si te podemos ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Estoy enviando datos, si no hay internet, deberia aguardarse los datos en formato .txt, como son varios datos cada tantos segundos, al enviarse un dato se crea un archivo por ejemplo "archivo_1.txt", si se notifica otro dato se almacena creandose otro "archivo_2.txt" y asi hasta que detecte que hay internet de nuevo y se envien los datos. Si en el lapso donde no hubo internet solo se enviaron 50 datos, se deverian crear "archivo_1.txt" hasta "archivo_50.txt". No se si me explique?

Comment: Para hacer eso basta con usar como nombre del archivo `nombre = "archivo_{}".format(n)`, donde n es una variable que aumentas en 1 cada vez que llamas a la función. No obstante, esto es lo básico falta saber el comportamiento de tu app: no especidicas en tu pregunta si cada vez que se reconecta esta información se envia o algo y se elimina del disco o si los archivos se mantienen indefinidamente. Tampoco dices que pasa cuando detienes el script y lo ejecutas más tarde de nuevo ¿Debe seguir creando archivos siguiendo la numeración donde se quedó en la última ejecución o reescribirlos?.

Comment: como inicializo la variable (n)?

Comment: Si no vas a usar clases la inicializas fuera de la funcion con `n = 1` para que sea una variable global, dentro de la función usas `global` para poder modificarla (`global n`) y al final de tu función le sumas 1 (`n += 1`).